# Angular: Redirect to login page along with error message

Tags: angular

What I am trying to achieve is if a session has timed out from any page I am redirecting the user to login page and I would like to show some error. Right now I am able to redirect but the error part is not working.

This is my httpInterceptor

```
@app.service 'httpInterceptor', [
  '$window',
  'AuthenticationService'
  ($window, AuthenticationService) ->
    {
      responseError: (res) ->
        if res.status == 403
          AuthenticationService.error = true;
          $window.location.href = '/'
        res
    }
]
```

and in the login controller I am trying to use this service

```
@app.service 'AuthenticationService', ->
  @error = false
  return
```

`AuthenticationService.error` but I am still getting this value as false.

EDIT JS code

```
this.app.service('httpInterceptor', [
  '$window',
  'AuthenticationService',
  ($window, AuthenticationService) =>
    ({
      responseError(res) {
        if (res.status === 403) {
          AuthenticationService.error = true;
          $window.location.href = '/';
        }
        return res;
      }
    })

]);
```

Service

```
this.app.service('AuthenticationService', function() {
  this.error = false;
});
```

Comment: what language is this? coffeescript? with angular :)?

Comment: yes it is coffeescript

Comment: @PierreDuc I have added JS code

Comment: you should try to use the router to change your location

Answer (score 0):

Use $location service if you are using locationRouter or use $state service if you are using stateProvider for view changing.

Example - $location.path('/');
$state.go('/');

This will avoid resetting the service value, which you have set for error message.

```
 this.app.service('httpInterceptor', [
  '$window',
  'AuthenticationService','$location;, '$state',
  ($window, AuthenticationService) =>
    ({
      responseError(res) {
        if (res.status === 403) {
          AuthenticationService.error = true;
          //$window.location.href = '/'; // instead of this
          // Use below
          $state.go('/'); or $location.path('/');

        }
        return res;
      }
    })

]);
```

Comment: Don't forget to inject the service as I have done there.

Comment: I have tried both location and state, with location it just adds `#/` without changing, it is not a single page app. Also with $state I am getting errors.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `$window.location.href = '/';` your page has to be reloaded, so everything you set to service is cleared after refresh. If you don't really need to refresh your page, go with `$location` or `$state` as suggested. If you still want to reload page, you need to path information between pages/states. You can do that using `localStorage` or just add query parameter to url `.href = '/?authError=Y'` and read + clean it on app bootstrap.

Update: based on your comments, you need to redirect to another page, that is not angular-page? If so, you cannot user neither `$location` nor `$state` as angular doesn't know how to resolve those (you can do `$location.href = "\"`, but that is same as `$window.location.href = '/';`).

P.S. cofeescript... you are pervert :-P